# Task bar: How should I optimise this js code to change description of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have list-group items, 7 per one column. Each one has an id #a1 #b2 and etc. I use Simple Slider and have two columns on each slide: one with list and one with description #descr. I need to change #descr each time one of list items is being clicked. Is there any way to optimise this to work and look shorter?

JQuery code:

```
function chnga(num, descr){
    $(num).click(function(){
    $("#descr").html(descr);
    })
};
var t1="Task 1";
var t2="Task 2";
var t3="Task 3";
var t4="Task 4";
var t5="Task 5";
var t6="Task 6";
var t7="Task 7";
chnga('#a1', t1);
chnga('#a2', t2);
chnga('#a3', t3);
chnga('#a4', t4);
chnga('#a5', t5);
chnga('#a6', t6);
chnga('#a7', t7);
function chngb(num, descr){
    $(num).click(function(){
    $("#bdescr").html(descr);
    })
};
chngb('#b1', t1);
chngb('#b2', t2);
chngb('#b3', t3);
chngb('#b4', t4);
chngb('#b5', t5);
chngb('#b6', t6);
chngb('#b7', t7);
function chngc(num, descr){
    $(num).click(function(){
    $("#cdescr").html(descr);
    })
};
chngc('#c1', t1);
chngc('#cс2', t2);
chngc('#c3', t3);
chngc('#c4', t4);
chngc('#c5', t5);
chngc('#c6', t6);
chngc('#c7', t7);
function chngd(num, descr){
    $(num).click(function(){
    $("#ddescr").html(descr);
    })
};
chngd('#d1', t1);
chngd('#d2', t2);
chngd('#d3', t3);
chngd('#d4', t4);
chngd('#d5', t5);
chngd('#d6', t6);
chngd('#d7', t7);
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 offset-md-1 offset-lg-1 offset-xl-1">
                                <div class="shadow-none clean-pricing-item" style="border-top: 2px solid #4caf50;">
                                    <div class="ribbon"><span>Новые!</span></div>
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h3>Available</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="a1"><span>Задание 1</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="a2"><span>List Group Item 2</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="a3"><span>List Group Item 3</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="a4"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="a5"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="a6"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="a7"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 offset-lg-0 offset-xl-0" id="c2">
                                <div class="text-left shadow-none clean-pricing-item" style="border-top: 5px solid #4caf50;height: 458px;">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h3>Description</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;"><span id="descr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div style="margin-top: 20px;"><i class="fab fa-python float-left" id="ai1" style="filter: blur(0px);font-size: 42px;margin-right: 15px;"></i><i class="fab fa-js border rounded-circle shadow-lg float-left" id="ai2" style="filter: blur(0px);font-size: 42px;"></i>
                                        <button
                                            class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="button">Принять</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shadow-none swiper-slide">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 offset-md-1 offset-lg-1 offset-xl-1">
                                <div class="shadow-none clean-pricing-item" style="border-top: 2px solid #FFC107;">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h3>Busy</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="b1"><span class="editable">List Group Item 1</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="b2"><span class="editable">List Group Item 2</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="b3"><span class="editable">List Group Item 3</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="b4"><span class="editable">List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="b5"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="b6"><span class="editable">List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="b7"><span class="editable">List Group Item</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 offset-lg-0 offset-xl-0" id="c2">
                                <div class="text-left shadow-none clean-pricing-item" style="border-top: 5px solid #ffc107;height: 458px;">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h3>Description</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;"><span id="bdescr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div style="margin-top: 15px;"><i class="fab fa-python" id="ai1" style="filter: blur(0px);font-size: 42px;margin-right: 15px;"></i><i class="fab fa-js border rounded-circle shadow-lg" id="ai2" style="filter: blur(0px);font-size: 42px;"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shadow-none swiper-slide">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px;">
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 offset-md-1 offset-lg-1 offset-xl-1">
                                <div class="shadow-none clean-pricing-item" style="border-top: 2px solid #ced8d1;">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h3>Pending</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="c1"><span class="editable">List Group Item 1</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="cc2"><span>List Group Item 2</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="c3"><span>List Group Item 3</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="c4"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="c5"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="c6"><span class="editable">List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="c7"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 offset-lg-0 offset-xl-0" id="c2">
                                <div class="shadow-none clean-pricing-item" style="border-top: 5px solid #ced8d1;height: 458px;">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h3>Description</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;"><span id="cdescr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div style="margin-top: 15px;"><i class="fab fa-python" id="ai1" style="font-size: 42px;margin-right: 15px;"></i><i class="fab fa-js border rounded-circle shadow-lg" id="ai2" style="filter: blur(0px);font-size: 42px;"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shadow-none swiper-slide">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px;">
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 offset-md-1 offset-xl-1">
                                <div class="shadow-none clean-pricing-item" style="border-top: 2px solid #7a1e99;">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h3>Complete</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="d1"><span class="editable">List Group Item 1</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="d2"><span class="editable">List Group Item 2</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="d3"><span class="editable">List Group Item 3</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="d4"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="d5"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="d6"><span>List Group Item</span></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item" id="d7"><span id="d7" class="editable">List Group Item</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 offset-lg-0 offset-xl-0" id="c2">
                                <div class="text-left shadow-none clean-pricing-item" style="border-top: 5px solid #7a1e99;height: 458px;">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h3 id="ah1">Description</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 276px;"><span id="ddescr">Описание выбранного задания.</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div style="margin-top: 15px;"><i class="fab fa-python" id="ai1" style="filter: blur(0px);font-size: 42px;margin-right: 15px;"></i><i class="fab fa-js border rounded-circle shadow-lg" id="ai2" style="filter: blur(0px);font-size: 42px;"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-left d-flex float-left swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="text-right d-flex float-right swiper-button-next"></div>
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple selector and using data attributes.

```js
$('[data-target]').on("click", function() {
  const clicked = $(this).addClass("active");
  clicked.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(clicked.data('target')).text(clicked.data('value'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-target="#out1" data-value="Task 1">One</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-target="#out1" data-value="Task 2">Two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-target="#out1" data-value="Task 3">Three</li>
</ul>

<h2 id="out1"></h2>


<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-target="#out2" data-value="Task 1">One</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-target="#out2" data-value="Task 2">Two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-target="#out2" data-value="Task 3">Three</li>
</ul>

<h2 id="out2"></h2>
```

Could move the target to the parent to make it a bit shorter

```js
$('[data-target]').on("click", "[data-value]", function() {
  const clicked = $(this).addClass("active");
  clicked.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(clicked.parent().data('target')).text(clicked.data('value'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="list-group"  data-target="#out1">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-value="Task 1">One</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-value="Task 2">Two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-value="Task 3">Three</li>
</ul>

<h2 id="out1"></h2>


<ul class="list-group" data-target="#out2">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-value="Task 1">One</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-value="Task 2">Two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-value="Task 3">Three</li>
</ul>

<h2 id="out2"></h2>
```

If the text is repeated, can use index

```js
const tasks = ["Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3"]

$('[data-target]').on("click", "li", function() {
  const clicked = $(this).addClass("active");
  clicked.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(clicked.parent().data('target')).text(tasks[clicked.index()]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="list-group"  data-target="#out1">
  <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
</ul>

<h2 id="out1"></h2>


<ul class="list-group" data-target="#out2">
  <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
</ul>

<h2 id="out2"></h2>
```